Brightway2.5, transform database to datapackgem, then add characterization factor matrix to datapackage
I am using new brightway2.5. Aiming to use the datapackage transformed from database directly to do LCA. I encountered an error, if anyone knows or give me some feedback, please do that, thanks in advance.
I convert database to datapackge using function datapackage(). But the converted datapackge has no characterization factors, so I add it using add_persistent_array method. But I encounterred an error.
My code:
    bd.projects.set_current("datapackage")

    mymethod2 = ["Global Warming", "CO2"]

    impact_category_to_index = {cat: i for i, cat in enumerate(mymethod2)}
    indices_int = np.array([(impact_category_to_index['Global Warming'], impact_category_to_index['CO2'])], dtype=[('row', np.int32), ('col', np.int32)])
    data = np.array([[0.5, 1.2]])
    
    # Create datapackge
    dp = bd.Database("data_package").datapackage()
    dp.add_persistent_array(
        matrix="characterization matrix",
        indices_array=np.array([indices_int]),
        data_array=data,
    )

My error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Documents/github/LCA-Experiments/OAT_datapackge.py", line 80, in <module>
    dp.add_persistent_array(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/bw2.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw_processing/datapackage.py", line 566, in add_persistent_array
    self._add_numpy_array_resource(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/bw2.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw_processing/datapackage.py", line 719, in _add_numpy_array_resource
    file_writer(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/bw2.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw_processing/io_helpers.py", line 132, in file_writer
    with fs.open(resource, mode="wb") as fo:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/bw2.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py", line 1303, in open
    f = self._open(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/bw2.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fsspec/implementations/zip.py", line 128, in _open
    raise OSError("ZipFS can only be open for reading or writing, not both")
OSError: ZipFS can only be open for reading or writing, not both

I expacted characterization factor data can be added by add_persistent_array method. Or am I using the wrong method?
